# Go Gin have problems with serving html files. File path that I'm providing seems to be ok - c.HTML returns nil pointer dereference err

Tags: go, http, runtime-error, go-gin

## I have this simple **main.go** server file that is supposed to serve html files on GET requests.

*(please note that I'm a learner)*
I am getting errors:

```
    runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference  
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:937 (0x72c17c)  
             (\*Context).HTML: instance := c.engine.HTMLRender.Instance(name, obj)  
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/main.go:28 (0x736fe4)  
             main.serveHTML.func1: c.HTML(http.StatusOK, filename, nil)
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:174 (0x730d79)
             (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/recovery.go:102 (0x730d67)
             CustomRecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:174 (0x72ff1d)
             (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/logger.go:240 (0x72feec)
             LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:174 (0x72efda)
             (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/gin.go:620 (0x72ec6d)
             (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/gin.go:576 (0x72e91c)
             (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2938 (0x62136d)
             serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req
```

when I try to `curl {ip}/newsim`.

The code I am using is as follows:

```go
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "os/exec"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
        "os"
    )

    func main() {
        r := gin.Default()

        // Serve different HTML files based on routes
        r.GET("/newsim", serveHTML("html/index1.html"))
        r.GET("/newsim/modular", serveHTML("html/index2.html"))

        // Define routes to execute Go scripts
        r.POST("/runscript1", executeGoScript("scripts/ResetLXI.go"))
        r.POST("/runscript2", executeGoScript("scripts/script2.go"))

        fmt.Println("Server is running on :8001...")
        r.Run(":8001")
    }

    func serveHTML(filename string) gin.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.HTML(http.StatusOK, filename, nil)
        }
    }

    func executeGoScript(scriptPath string) gin.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c *gin.Context) {
            cmd := exec.Command("go", "run", scriptPath)
            cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
            cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
            if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
                c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error executing script: %v", err)
                return
            }
            c.String(http.StatusOK, "Script executed successfully.")
        }
    }
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/main.go  
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/html/index1.html  
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/html/index2.html  
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/scripts/ResetLXI.go  
    /lxi/pil/www/bin/sim/scripts/script2.go
```

Can you help me understand why I am getting this error and possibly how to fix it?
(newbie in go btw)

I've tried to print out the filename string in serverHTMl function, it looks ok tho.
I don't really think the problem is related to path to .html file but since I'm learner my assumption is just an assumption.

Comment: You first need to load the html files for `c.HTML` to work (using `LoadHTMLGlob` or `LoadHTMLFiles`). See: https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/html-rendering/. And note that once you load the files you should use the base file name (without the `html/` directory prefix) in `c.HTML`, if you want a different name then you must specify that name in the html file itself using the `{{ define ... }}` action, as you can see in the linked examples.

Comment: Note also that if you pass relative file paths to `LoadHTMLGlob` and/or `LoadHTMLFiles`, then those file paths will be resolved relative to the running process' _working directory_; this means that depending on where from the program is executed, the files may _or may not_ be found.